# Meta reviews on review page

Tags: feature-request, review, per-site-meta

I've just noticed on the review queue for all sites that Meta Reviews appears as below. On Super User to use a specific example I noticed there are outstanding review items on meta but on the main site the review queue is listed as below. Are there any plans to update it to show outstanding items awaiting review or is it simply a reminder for reviewers to pay attention to meta reviews from time to time?

[image: Meta reviews]

Comment: It is probably just a reminder.

Comment: @Martijn seems like it is but would be interesting to know if it's part of a future plan. Just doing a check on EE.Meta seems like there's been under 50 reviews ever so I can imagine on some sites it might end up being ignored.

Comment: @PeterJ My thought exactly. I've supposed there will be something. There was nothing.

Comment: Is there any proof making this suggestion useful?

Comment: Would be a much more effective reminder with a number by it! If you know there's never anything on the other side, you won't be inclined to click and check. But if it has a nonzero number... we're pretty trained to click on those on the review page!

Comment: You might want to turn this into a feature request. This would be really useful especially on smaller/beta sites where the meta review queue only gets one item a month or something.

Comment: @Werner not everything has to be "useful", this is just something nice to have, kind of additional stat.