# Can we show how many meta reviews there are?

Tags: feature-request, review, per-site-meta

[image: pic]
Can we show how many meta reviews there are, like all other review tasks?
Just add a number in the blank space on the left.

Comment: I *think* it used to show a number, didn't it?

Comment: @Sha no of course, it didn't use to :) it is a new section, as far as you and I know - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248511/meta-reviews-on-review-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can :)

I made a user script for this purpose, which shows the number of available reviews on the local per-site meta.

There's how it looks:

> [image]

## [Download!](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8721-meta-reviews-counter)

Comment: (oh wait - Pluralisation Bug.)

Comment: How does the load function work cross-domain!?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I have no idea. Never thought about it, therefore it works :P

Comment: Lol fair enough ;)